# Word for something that is modified

Tags: single-word-requests

I am using the word *modifier* to descrive something that modifies something else. What word should I use to describe what is being modified?

For example, in the sentence,

> Fat John ate slowly

*Fat* and *slowly* are my modifiers (an adjective and an adverb, respectively), but what word should I use to describe *John* and *ate*? *Modifiee* is not a word.

Comment: You might say "the modifier and its modified element" or "the modified element".

Comment: How about _modifiend_ ?

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/417271/2085).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a specific linguistic term. But I don't know it, and I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't one.

So how about **subject**? Or if that's got too many connotations for the context, perhaps **target**?

LATER - I'm also minded to wonder *why* there might not be an established term. Adjectives and adverbs are easily-identified 'modifiers', but actually a modifier can be a pretty long subordinate clause in a sentence. And the text element(s) it modifies can be complex too.

The lack of a term might simply be down to the conceptual difficulty of naming something so epen-ended. It might just be the *noun next to the modifying adjective*, or it might be the *whole sentence excluding the modifier*. All they have in common is the capacity to *be* modified - not a very significant attribute for most considerations.

At least with actual modifiers, you could say their capacity to modify is a *defining* characteristic, so it makes some sense to identify and name such a linguistic class. The things which they modify are so heterogeneous it's a bitmeaningless to lump them all together as a class with a specific name.

Cutting to the chase, I realised that the obvious candidate would be **modificand** if I really needed such a word, and Lo! - it turns out linguists [do indeed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/modificand) use that term when pressed.

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn: I just realised why *modificand* eluded you in the first place. You derived the non-existent word *modifee* because you started by thinking of common word endings for the required sense, and -ee is certainly a standard default for common words. I started by thinking of 'techie' words like *multiply*. Incidentally, I just discovered while writing this that the techie rule even works to give us **subtractand**, but even professional mathematicians probably rarely have need to use that word!

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a generally accepted word: **[head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28linguistics%29)**.

- *Fat John* is a noun phrase and *John* its head.
- *Eat slowly* is sometimes considered a verb phrase, and *eat* would be its head.
- *Computer-related* is a compound adjective / adjective phrase, and *related* is its head.

The head of a phrase is its core, the part that determines how the phrase as a whole behaves. As you can see, the head of a noun phrase must be a word that functions as a noun, etc.

Comment: You're quite right. I did know of this usage, but I forgot it. Mind you, it took a while to get my head around *Computer-related*, and I doubt I'd have got there at all if I hadn't persevered because I knew you were bound to be right!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, such a word would simply be referred to as a noun, verb, or whatever other appellation is appropriate for it (e.g., if the modifier affects a direct object, you would just call it a direct object).

It does seem odd that although linguists seemingly have a name for everything else, there isn't a widely-used label for the thing that a modifier affects. Perhaps that's because a "modifier" doesn't actually *modify* anything so much as it provides more information. John is still John, whether he's fat or thin.

Comment: It depends on how you define *[modify](http://www.bing.com/Dictionary/search?q=define+modify)*.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is *antecedent*.

In your example, fat is an adjective and slowly is an adverb. Technically, an adjective "qualifies" a noun and an adverb modifies a verb.