# What does one call the noun a preposition relates to its object?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

With minimal research online one can easily find that a prepositional phrase consists of a preposition and an object. Most online and paper resources will describe a preposition as a word that describes the relationship between two nouns/noun phrases.

For example

*The cat is behind the table.*

OR

*The cat behind the table was eating the leftovers.*

I know that you refer to *behind* as the preposition, *the table* as the object of the preposition, but am confused as to if there is a word to describe the relationship between *behind* and *the cat*. I am looking for a word for that specific relationship, not simply that in the first example, *the cat* is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Wouldn't the object of the preposition be qualifying the subject of the preposition?

Comment: No: in your first example, the PP serves as a locative complement of "be", not "the cat" -- that is the syntactic relationship here. The PP does of course 'refer' to the subject "the cat", i.e. it has subject orientation, but that is a semantic relationship. In your second example, the PP is a modifier of "cat" -- that is the syntactic relationship here. Btw, prepositions take a few kinds of dependents as complement, not just objects, for example AdvPs, PPs and subordinate clauses.

Comment: Generally there is no special word for a noun modified by a prepositional phrase, just as there is no special word for a noun modified by an adjective. It's just modification (though one can be more specific about what kind of modification, but that's more semantic than grammatical).

Answer (score 0):

> The cat is behind the table.

Here *behind* is the head of a prepositional phrase acting as the subject complement of *to be,* meaning that it describes *the cat.*

> The cat behind the table was eating the leftovers.

Here *behind* is the head of a prepositional phrase modifying *the cat.*

Comment: And it doesn't have to be a noun: *The cat ran behind the table.*

Comment: This does not answer the Q! Also in “The cat is behind the table”, the PP is a locative complement of the verb *be* and not a modifier of the NP *the cat*.

Comment: While an argument can be made (and in linked questions, has been) that *modifiers modify **modificands** or modifiees*, this is at best language more technical than pedestrian. Related material: [“In linguistics, the most general term for relations between the elements of a phrase is *head* and *dependent*. The term that covers *modificand* is *head* although the meaning of *head* is more general”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2009_March_30).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Is *sweet* therefore a predicative complement that also “does not ‘modify’ the NP subject” in *Fresh flowers  smell **sweet** in your nose* and in *Fresh berries taste **sweet** on your sundae*?

Comment: How about _Grilled spinach lies flat on the plate_ or _This toy goes boom whenever you touch it_?